# Access JSON nested property using dynamic proprty name

Tags: json, powershell

Let's say I have JSON object

```json
{
    "trigger": {
        "schedule.main": {
            "interval": "5m"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to modify "5m" to "10m".

This can be achieved easily when I explicitly type in the script the entire path to the variable to change:

```bsh
$jsonStr = @'
{
    "trigger": {
        "schedule.main": {
            "interval": "5m"
        }
    }
}
'@

$jsonObj = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonStr

Write-Output ($jsonObj | ConvertTo-Json)
$jsonObj.trigger."schedule.main".interval = "10m"
Write-Output ($jsonObj | ConvertTo-Json)
```

Now I would like to achive the same result with the full path to the property provided as a string (this comes from some config file along with the value to change):

```bsh
$propertyPath = "trigger.""schedule.main"".interval"
```

How to achieve this in a PowerShell script, so I don't hard-code the path to the property name, but build it dynamically from the provided string?

I tried `iex`, which modifies a copy of the JSON object:

```bsh
$prop = (iex "`$jsonObj.$propertyPath")
$prop = "30m"
```

The main `$jsonObj` remains unmodified, which is a problem.

Comment: `but I need to build it dynamically...` what does that mean?

Comment: I see many similar questions when googling. For example [Problems parsing / accessing nested JSON / Hashtable data via variables in Powershell](//stackoverflow.com/a/41878478)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for the hint with iex which allows to "read" the property, but I need to update the value as well

Comment: Eh? The answer I've linked describes several solutions, including the one you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you, please, point out how to modify the value of the property  as part of the main json object, not just to get the value?

Comment: Ok, I figured that this works: iex "`$jsonObj.$propertyPath = ""30m"""  - i have to wrap up the modification into iex; although it's not nice it works! Thanks

Comment: Please do not edit answers into questions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, sure, basically, whoever experience the same problem will have to dig through another post to deduct the solution or read these comments - no big deal :)